# closed parenthesis ruby method

Tags: ruby, loops

Can someone explain what is making this method exit the loop after the first pair?

```
  def closed_parens(string)

   chars = string.split(//)

   chars.each_with_index do |c, i|

    if c == "("

      chars.shift
      if chars[0] != ")"
        return false 
      else 
        chars.shift 
      end 

    elsif c == "{"

      chars.shift 
      if chars[0] != "}"
        return false 
      elsif 
        chars.shift
      end 

    elsif c == "["

      chars.shift 
      if chars[0] != "]"
        return false 
      else 
        chars.shift 
      end 

    end

  end 

  if chars.length > 0 
    return false 
  else 
    return true 
  end 
end 

closed_parens("{}{}")
```

Comment: It's time to meet the [`case`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-case+Expression) statement. This could also be improved by having a lookup table of the matching pairs: `{ '[' => ']', '(' => ')', '<' => '>', ... }` for example.

Comment: yep, I know that's most ideal, i wanted to write this method in every way I could think of for practice :) thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to use `shift` on a Enumerable object while you are iterating over it.

You may want to look into the [Enumerable#each_cons](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons) method where you could do something like

```
[your enumerable item].each_cons(2) do |current_item, next_item|
   # do some work...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the fact that you call `shift` on the array as you iterate through it.

For example:

```
[1] pry(main)> a = [1,2,3,4]
=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
[2] pry(main)> a.each { puts a.shift }
1
2
=> [3, 4]
[3] pry(main)>
```

The `each` doesn't run 4 times, it only runs 2 times because of the shift.

Comment: Ahh i see, thank you yea that makes sense.  I'll try another way